# Remove space between lists within latex table

Tags: tables, spacing, lists

I wish to remove the spaces shown by the red lines on the image provided. I have tried numerous methods and can't seem to get it right. Thanks in advance.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centerline{
\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}||p{2cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|  }
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Competitors for Boredome} \\
    \hline
    Product Name & Price & Advantages & Disadvantages\\
    \hline
    Rendever (Virtual Reality)  & AU\$2064 
    & \begin{itemize} [leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
        \item Designed for elderly
        \item Reminiscence therapy
        \item Proven 40\% increased happiness
    \end{itemize}
    & \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
        \item Disorientating
        \item Removes social aspects
    \end{itemize}\\    

    AV1 (Learning Avatar) & AU\$2833 
    & \begin{itemize} [leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
        \item Students can learn from home
        \item Designed for classrooms
        \item Acts as eyes, ears and voice
    \end{itemize}
    & \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
        \item Limited target market
        \item May get easily lost 
        \item Dependent on others moving the robot
    \end{itemize}\\

    KOMP (1-button computer) & AU\$1000 
    & \begin{itemize} [leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
        \item Easy for elderly to use
        \item Reconnect and keep updated with family
    \end{itemize}
    & \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
        \item Limited target market
        \item Limited functionality
    \end{itemize}\\

    Sony Aibo (Robotic Pet Dog)  & AU\$3000 
    & \begin{itemize} [leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
        \item Provides distraction
        \item Acts as company
        \item Less mess and responsibilities than a real pet
    \end{itemize}
    & \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
        \item Doesn't help with social isolation
    \end{itemize}\\

    Social Media (Facebook) & AU\$0 
& \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
    \item Message, video chat and share photos
\end{itemize}
&\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
    \item Perceived social interactions
    \item Difficult for some people to use
    \item Requires personal information
\end{itemize}\\

    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Social Isolation Product Competitors}
\label{tbl:table1}
\end{table}
```

[image: Image supplied]

Comment: please make your MWE complete.

Comment: @emmjay could you have a look at the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add option `noitemsep` to itemize list, and where still not satisfied with extra spacing add negative vertical space with `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` --the example of your table partly shown below in screenshot

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}||p{2cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|  }
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Competitors for Boredome} \\
            \hline
            Product Name & Price & Advantages & Disadvantages\\
            \hline
            Rendever (Virtual Reality)  & AU\$2064 
            & {\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{itemize} [leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt] 
                \item Designed for elderly
                \item Reminiscence therapy
                \item Proven 40\% increased happiness
            \end{itemize}}
            & \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt] 
                \item Disorientating
                \item Removes social aspects
            \end{itemize}\\    

            AV1 (Learning Avatar) & AU\$2833 
            & {\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{itemize} [leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt] 
                \item Students can learn from home
                \item Designed for classrooms
                \item Acts as eyes, ears and voice
            \end{itemize}}
            & {\vspace{-\baselineskip}
              \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
                \item Limited target market
                \item May get easily lost 
                \item Dependent on others moving the robot
            \end{itemize}}\\

            KOMP (1-button computer) & AU\$1000 
            & \begin{itemize} [leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
                \item Easy for elderly to use
                \item Reconnect and keep updated with family
            \end{itemize}
            & \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
                \item Limited target market
                \item Limited functionality
            \end{itemize}\\

            Sony Aibo (Robotic Pet Dog)  & AU\$3000 
            & \begin{itemize} [leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
                \item Provides distraction
                \item Acts as company
                \item Less mess and responsibilities than a real pet
            \end{itemize}
            & \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
                \item Doesn't help with social isolation
            \end{itemize}\\

            Social Media (Facebook) & AU\$0 
            & \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
                \item Message, video chat and share photos
            \end{itemize}
            &\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep] 
                \item Perceived social interactions
                \item Difficult for some people to use
                \item Requires personal information
            \end{itemize}\\

            \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! 
Worked perfectly !!

Answer (score 1):

- please always provide complete, compilable small document with your table. Such document provide in its preamble information about your document's page layout, used relevant packages etc, which influence on your table design.
- for columns, where contents have only one line, I would rather use `l` and `r˛column types
- for more vertical spaces in cells I suggest to use `makegapedcells` macro from the `makecell` package
- with `\setlist` I would define common style for `itemize` list in table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm,
            showframe]{geometry} % in real document remove "showframe" option
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 label=\textbullet,
                 after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                 before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                 }
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |l||r|*{2}{>{\RaggedRight}p{4.5cm}|}  }
    \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Competitors for Boredome} \\
    \hline
Product Name & Price & Advantages & Disadvantages\\
    \hline
Rendever (Virtual Reality)  & AU\$2064
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Designed for elderly
    \item Reminiscence therapy
    \item Proven 40\% increased happiness
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Disorientating
        \item Removes social aspects
            \end{itemize}\\
AV1 (Learning Avatar) & AU\$2833
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Students can learn from home
    \item Designed for classrooms
    \item Acts as eyes, ears and voice
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Limited target market
        \item May get easily lost
        \item Dependent on others moving the robot
            \end{itemize}\\
KOMP (1-button computer) & AU\$1000
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Easy for elderly to use
    \item Reconnect and keep updated with family
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Limited target market
        \item Limited functionality
            \end{itemize}\\
Sony Aibo (Robotic Pet Dog)  & AU\$3000
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Provides distraction
    \item Acts as company
    \item Less mess and responsibilities than a real pet
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Doesn't help with social isolation
            \end{itemize}\\
Social Media (Facebook) & AU\$0
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Message, video chat and share photos
\end{itemize}
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Perceived social interactions
    \item Difficult for some people to use
    \item Requires personal information
        \end{itemize}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Social Isolation Product Competitors}
\label{tbl:table1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic:
You my consider the following design of your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry} % in real document remove "showframe" option
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 label=\textbullet,
                 after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                 before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                 }
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l r *{2}{>{\RaggedRight}X} @{}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Competitors for Boredome} \\
    \midrule
Product Name & Price & Advantages & Disadvantages\\
    \midrule
Rendever (Virtual Reality)  & AU\$2064
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Designed for elderly
    \item Reminiscence therapy
    \item Proven 40\% increased happiness
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Disorientating
        \item Removes social aspects
            \end{itemize}\\
AV1 (Learning Avatar) & AU\$2833
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Students can learn from home
    \item Designed for classrooms
    \item Acts as eyes, ears and voice
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Limited target market
        \item May get easily lost
        \item Dependent on others moving the robot
            \end{itemize}\\
KOMP (1-button computer) & AU\$1000
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Easy for elderly to use
    \item Reconnect and keep updated with family
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Limited target market
        \item Limited functionality
            \end{itemize}\\
Sony Aibo (Robotic Pet Dog)  & AU\$3000
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Provides distraction
    \item Acts as company
    \item Less mess and responsibilities than a real pet
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item Doesn't help with social isolation
            \end{itemize}\\
Social Media (Facebook) & AU\$0
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Message, video chat and share photos
\end{itemize}
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Perceived social interactions
    \item Difficult for some people to use
    \item Requires personal information
        \end{itemize}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Social Isolation Product Competitors}
\label{tbl:table1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]