# Making a table with indentation

Tags: tables

I need some help to make this in latex. The problem is that the text expands the page and I am not able to make indentations/bullet points. To illustrate how it is supposed to look I made the table in Word.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far to achieve the output you want to get. Taking an existing code and modifying it to produce the desired output is a lot easier than having to retype everything from a screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! What you try so far? Where you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the answer here -- [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546418/remove-space-between-lists-within-latex-table]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546418/remove-space-between-lists-within-latex-table%5D)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm,
%showframe
]{geometry} % in real document remove "showframe" option
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
leftmargin=*,
label=\textbullet,
after=\end{minipage}, % <---
before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{>{\RaggedRight}p{6cm}} }
\toprule[2pt]
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Table with Indentation} \\
\midrule
Prcess Related & Product Related & Management Related\\
\midrule
TEAMS & LCA & Reporting Frameworks \\
\begin{itemize}
    \item Students can learn from home
    \item Designed for classrooms
    \item Acts as eyes, ears and voice
\end{itemize} 
& Technology Board
& \begin{itemize}
\item Students can learn from home
\item Designed for classrooms
\begin{itemize}
    \item Repeat Designed for classrooms
\end{itemize}
\item Acts as eyes, ears and voice
\end{itemize} \\
& &  Easy for elderly to use \\
& & Less mess and responsibilities than a real pet\\
& & \begin{itemize}
\item Message, video chat and share photos
\end{itemize} \\
\bottomrule[2pt]
\end{tabular}
\caption{Social Isolation Product Competitors}
\label{tbl:table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions:

- Use a `tabularx` environment to allow automatic line breaking in columns 1 and 3
- Employ the `enumitem` package to create bespoke itemize-type list environments that use less vertical space than the ordinary `enumitem` environment does.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page parameters suitably
\usepackage{ragged2e,booktabs}

\usepackage{tabularx}
% define a variable-width form of the 'X' column type:
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize%
                       \RaggedRight}X}

\usepackage{enumitem}
% create a new, two-level itemize-like list environment:
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[myitemize,1]{label=-,nosep,left=0pt,
          before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
          after =\end{minipage}}
\setlist[myitemize,2]{label=$\circ$,nosep,left=1em,
          before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\hsize-1em\relax}\RaggedRight},
          after =\strut\end{minipage}}
          
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L{0.7} l L{1.3} @{}} % 0.7+1.3=2=# of X-type columns
\toprule
Process related & Product related & Management related \\
\midrule
TEAMS & LCA & Reporting frameworks \\[1ex]
\begin{myitemize}
\item An environmental management tool
\item Local scope: Hydro-Aluminum Sunndal
\end{myitemize} &
Technology Board & 
\begin{myitemize}
\item UN Global Compact 
\item GRI Standards

  \begin{myitemize}
  \item Nr.\ 101 (2016) define which topics and indicators 
        that are material to report upon
  \end{myitemize}
\item The International Council on Mining and Metals (ICMM)
\item Position statements and the Aluminium Stewardship Initiative (ASI)
\end{myitemize} \\
&& Better-Bigger-Greener program\\[1ex]
&& Review of climate-related risks, 2018
\begin{myitemize}
\item physical, technological, commercial, legal and reputational risk
\end{myitemize} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
\begin{tabularx}
```

Comment: shucks a feww seconds delay

Comment: What is the meaning of \hsize?

Comment: @Diaa - `\hsize` (short for “horizontal size”, I suppose) is a length parameter that comes up frequently in `tabularx` environments.

Comment: Another question if you don't mind: I am familiar with the usage of only \hsize=#1\hsize, but I don't quite understand the meaning of \hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize. So, I hope you would explain it? Thanks

Comment: @Diaa - I don't mind at all; I'm always happy to discuss the fine points of LaTeX-based typesetting. :-) In general circumstances, ` \hsize=#1\hsize` suffices to get the desired column width. However, if the column in question contains a list-like environment, as is the case here, `\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize` is required; see [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532586/5001) for more on this subject. (In case you're not sure what the connection of that posting to list-like environments is: Theorem-like environments are generally based on `trivlist`-type structures.)

Comment: So, my question is really valid :) Thanks for letting me know that I have to adopt the new approach from now on.